# Finding $\min_{x,y\ge0} (x+y)$ such that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\ge c$ for a given constant $c\ge0$

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-writing, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For a given real number $c\ge0$, we want to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\min_{x,y}\ &x+y\\
\text{subject to}\ \ \ &\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\ge c\\
&x,y\ge 0
\end{align}

To solve it, I first want to show that in an optimal solution we must have $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = c$. I am not sure if this step is required to solve this optimization problem. Although it seems to be obvious, I could not prove this property! To prove it by contradiction, I tried to show that the following sets of constraints cannot be true at the same time:
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} > \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\\
&x+y < a + b\\
&x,y, a , b\ge 0
\end{align}

I also tried to use the inequality $\sqrt{xy}\le\frac{x+y}{2}$ but it did not work. I am not sure what is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x+y\geq\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2\geq\frac{c^2}{2}$$

Equality when $x=y=\frac{c^2}{4}$

To show the first inequality you can just open the brackets and apply AM-GM

Comment: Thanks, how can we show that the system of inequalities that I used to do a proof by contradiction can not be true at the same time?

Comment: @Opt You will not get a contradiction in that way, because you can, for example, take: $x= 2.00000000001^2, y=2^2, a= 3^2, b=1^2 $

Comment: @Opt You can actually prove that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ should be equal to $c$ in a bit different way, Suppose that you will get your min value at some point in which $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}>c$ than there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $\sqrt{x-\epsilon}+\sqrt{y}\geq c$. But  $x-\epsilon+y<x+y$ and here we will get a contradiction

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$x+y=\frac{1}{2}(1+1)(x+y)\geq\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1\cdot  {x}}+\sqrt{1\cdot y})^2\geq\frac{c^2}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $(1,1)||(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y})$ and $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=c,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x,y,c\ge 0$, you can square the constraint inequality:
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\ge c \iff x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\ge c^2.$$
Now use AM-GM:
$$x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}$$
to get:
$$2(x+y)=x+y+x+y\ge x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\ge c^2 \Rightarrow x+y\ge \frac{c^2}{2},$$
the equality occurs for $x=y=\frac{c^2}{4}$.